# Eclipse Indigo "Save Actions" are not being applied

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo

I'm new to Eclipse and downloaded the following version:
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Indigo Release
Build id: 20110615-0604

[edit] **Eclipse Platform Version 3.7**

I have edited Java > Editor > Save Actions to do the following: Remove trailing white spaces on all lines, Correct indentation

When I save the .java file, those actions are not applied... is this a bug?
Found this that might be related: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=350475

Comment: Well, this is a tumbleweed... Must be a bug, and I haven't discovered anything.

Comment: That's a bug report against the JAVASCRIPT tools, not the JAVA tools.  And it's the same restriction: the source file has to be in a recognized Source Folder.  Is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for those of you who have found this topic... I did find 2 solutions, no thanks to Eclipse, other than the fact that it is open source and people can write plugins.

**Eclipse Platform Version 3.7**

1. [AnyEdit](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/anyedit/) - plugin that does it for you when you Save file (I believe this is what eclipse SHOULD be doing)
2. Go to: Window > Preferences. Then under General > Keys. Make sure drop down for Scheme: is Default and enter 'remove trailing' in the filter. You should then see "Remove Trailing Whitespace" under the command column. Bind it to your own key command.

The only drawback to #2 is that you have to actually press the key binding while editing the file, kindof like a *cleanup* action.

Too bad Eclipse hasn't taken the approach that ALL file types should be configurable in this way... sometimes I miss TextPad.

Comment: Bond this on Ctrl+S while editing a JS file and this just fixed the issue

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that this relates to JavaScript files, then the related Eclipse bug could be helpful.

The problem (as I've just experienced) is that you can edit the JavaScript -> Save Actions preferences via the context menu when editing a JavaScript file, but the actions will not be run.

The solution is to right click on the project containing the .js file, and select Configure -> Convert to JavaScript project.

The bad news is that this will then will also enable Eclipse's not-so-great JavaScript validation, therefore telling you that libraries such as moment.min.js are broken.

Comment: Thank you! I found that my JavaScript save actions were not being executed at all on my .js files. In the Project Explorer, I right-clicked on the project and then selected Configure > Convert to JavaScript project. That fixed the issue! :-D

Comment: Glad my answer finally helped someone.  After all this time, I hope my comment on Eclipse's JS validation above is now out of date :)

Comment: I use Maven to build the project so I ignore Eclipse's JavaScript errors...

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but at least for newer Eclipse versions there's a better solution: Go to the **project properties**, then to **Project Facets**.  If it tells you that your project isn't in faceted form yet, then convert it.  Afterwards (or if it already was faceted), just **enable** the **JavaScript** checkbox.

I had the same issue with Eclipse 4.4 (Luna) and this fixed it for me, the save actions are now executed on save.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [jlh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26883768/5036067), I also had to configure the JavaScript include path of the project to enable save actions. Before that even a manual "Clean Up ..." from the source menu wouldn't work.